# Event handler does not fire with .on(), but works with .delegate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, bootstrap-modal, jquery-events

I'm using a Bootstrap Modal dialog, and I have an event handler set up so that once the modal closes, it triggers a couple of other updates on the page. I had been using the `.delegate` method which works perfectly. After reading that it was deprecated, I tried to move to the `.on` method, however the handler was not getting triggered. I cannot figure out why. Here are my two code snippets for comparison:

Delegate:

```
$(document).delegate('#streamingPopup', 'hide.bs.modal', function () { ... });
```

On:

```
$('#streamingPopup').on('hide.bs.modal', function () { ... });
```

No code withing the callback function has changed.

As far as I can tell, I'm using it the way the documentation says it should be used (http://api.jquery.com/on/). I'm assuming it has something to do with the `hide.bs.modal` event, or with the fact that it's attached directly to the jQuery object rather than the DOM itself, but I can't work out why it would work in one but not the other. Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's good to see that you read the doco, except that apparently you missed the sentence in the main description that said "For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see `.bind()`, [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), and `.live()`." - the doco for [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) explains how to use `.on()` to replace `.delegate()`. And you missed the section on [direct and delgated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change the syntax for `.on`:

```
$(document).on('hide.bs.modal', '#streamingPopup', function () { ... });
```

This must work, as it targets a static parent. Replace the `document` with a static parent of `#streamingPopup`.